# PHP Exec iptables

Tags: php, exec, root, iptables

I would like exec iptables from PHP.

I've added this line on my sudoers file:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s * -j ACCEPT
```

I tried also with

```
root ALL=(root) ALL apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s * -j ACCEPT
```

My server run on centos 7.

Then when I execute my script I got:

> Sorry, user apache is not allowed to execute '/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT' as apache on "servername" why ?

Part of my code:

```
$ip = $query['ip'];
$pattern = '/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/';
   if(preg_match($pattern , $ip) == true) {      
      $exec_cmd = "/usr/bin/sudo -u apache /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j ACCEPT 2>&1";
      echo('exec: ' . $exec_cmd); 
      $output = [];    
      $retval = 0;
      exec($exec_cmd, $output, $retval);
      print_r($output);
      echo($retval);         
} else {
      echo('Bad IP');
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I would highly advise against giving your web user sudo privileges. This sounds more like a server issue than PHP though.

Comment: [unix.se] would be a better place to ask how to configure `/etc/sudoers` properly to allow this.